# How to Disabling SharePoint TextField Control Programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spfield, field-controls

I'm developing a user control containing textfields bound to my list SPListFields and I'm using this user control twice with two different modes ( Edit or New).

In my Edit mode I want to disable a TextField wich is bound to the SPListItem Code but I didn't now how to do it from code behind ??

Here's the TextField Code :

```
TextField MyCode = new TextField();
MyCode.ID = "MyCodeID";
MyCode.FieldName = "Code";
MyCode.ItemId = myItemID;
MyCode.ListId = myListID;
MyCode.ControlMode = Mode == OperationMode.Edit ? SPControlMode.Edit : SPControlMode.New;
Page.Controls.Add(MyCode);
if (Mode == OperationMode.Edit)
{
    MyCode.enabledViewState = false // this doesn't enable my textField
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the field to appear as read-only or display than you can change its `SPControlMode` to `Display`

`MyCode.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display`

Answer (score 0):

enabledViewState wouldn't enable/disable your field, try .Enabled instead.

Comment: that option doesn't exist